# How to remove duplication row from dolphindb table?

Tags: dolphindb

How to select non duplicate row data from the table of DolphinDB? I found the function `distinct` in the manual. I tried the code below, but doesnt work.

```
select distinct(col1,col2) from table
=====================================
The function [distinct] expects 1 argument(s), but the actual number of arguments is: 2

select distinct([col1,col2]) from table
=====================================
The argument for 'distinct' must be a typed vector
```

It seems that distinct can only apply to one column. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The function `distinct` returns unique elements for a single column. If you want to filter out duplicate rows according to multiple columns, strongly recommend function `isDuplicated`, which was introduced to DolphinDB in version 0.99.

```
select * from table where isDuplicated([col1, col2], FIRST)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

USE master
GO

CREATE DATABASE TestDB
GO

USE TestDB
GO

CREATE TABLE TableA
(
 ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
 Value INT,
 CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)

---

USE TestDB
GO

INSERT INTO TableA(Value)
VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(5),(3),(5)

SELECT *
FROM TableA

SELECT Value, COUNT(*) AS DuplicatesCount
FROM TableA
GROUP BY Value

---

### Output:-

[image]

Try This Sql Statements It's Working